# Get UIView size in init method

Tags: uiview, size, init

When I call self.frame.size.height in the init method of my UIView I get 0 as result.

UIView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"Content,init: %f",self.frame.size.height);
...
```

UIView creation:

```
m_content = [[Content alloc] init];
m_content.frame=self.frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the frame (and with it the size) gets set AFTER the init routine.

Use

```
m_content = [[Content alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
```

instead of

```
m_content = [[Content alloc] init];
m_content.frame=self.frame;
```

Comment: Actually knew the answer all along. Cost me some time to find out. I thought i save people some time who get that problem by making that post.